Solving system under constraints
I have the system of two equations in the variable $\mu$ with real parameters $A$ and $E$: $$\begin{equation}\label{eq:waveaction_posMu}
    \frac{1}{2}A = -\frac{2T}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi^{2}}{3} + 2\mu}}\text{ArcTanh}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi^{2}}{3} + 2\mu}}}
\end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}
     \frac{1}{2}E =\pi T + \frac{\mu}{2}A
 \end{equation}$$
Given values of $E$ and $A$, I want to solve for $T$ and $\mu$.

Attempt: Define the system
eqCase2 = (A/2 == (-2  T  ArcTanh[\[Pi]/Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/3 + 2  \[Mu]]])/
      Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/3 + 2  \[Mu]] && e/2 == \[Pi]  T + (A  \[Mu])/2);

Eliminate the variable T to obtain an equation in mu for which we numerically solve for.
mueqCase2 = Eliminate[eqCase2, T]
mueqCase2Function[A_, e_, \[Mu]_] := 
  A^2  \[Pi]^2  (\[Pi]^2 + 6  \[Mu]) - 
   12  (e - A \[Mu])^2  ArcTanh[\[Pi]/Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/3 + 2 \[Mu]]]^2;

$$-12 A^2 \mu ^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2 \mu +\frac{\pi ^2}{3}}}\right)^2+6 \pi ^2 A^2 \mu +\pi ^4 A^2+24 A e \mu  \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2 \mu +\frac{\pi ^2}{3}}}\right)^2-12 e^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2 \mu +\frac{\pi ^2}{3}}}\right)^2=0$$
Solve for mu:
muSolutionsCase2 = 
 Flatten[Table[{A, e, 
    Flatten[NSolve[mueqCase2 && Pi^2/3 < \[Mu], \[Mu], Reals]][[1, 
      2]]}, {A, 1/100, 1, 1/10}, {e, 1/100, 1, 1/10}], 1]

The above is a Table containing {A,e,mu}. Now solve for T:
    TTempCase2 = 
      Flatten[Solve[eqCase2[[2]] /. {A -> #1, e -> #2, \[Mu] -> #3}, 
          T] & @@@ muSolutionsCase2, 1];
TSolutionsCase2 = T /. TTempCase2

Problems

I need mu to satisfy mu > Pi^2 / 3 and T to satisfy T < 0. I don't think T is always negative.
I think both A and e need to be positive. However, in the range I provide to NSolve, sometimes I do not get a solution for mu and this messes up the code I later use. If NSolve fails, how do I trash the attempt instead of storing {}?


It appears that the system eqCase2 has real solutions for some values of parameters from those ranges and does not have such solutions for some values of parameters from those ranges. Indeed,
eqCase2 = (A/2 == (-2  T  ArcTanh[\[Pi]/Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/3 + 2  \[Mu]]])/
  Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/3 + 2  \[Mu]] && e/2 == \[Pi]  T + (A  \[Mu])/2);
FindInstance[eqCase2&& T < 0 && \[Mu] > Pi^2/3 && A >= 1/100 && A <= 1 && 
e >= 1/100 &&  e <= 1, {\[Mu], T, A, e}, Reals]//N


{{\[Mu] -> 3.76732, T -> -0.179301, A -> 0.410763, e -> 0.42089}

and
A = 1/19; e = 1/2; FindInstance[ eqCase2 && 
T < 0 && \[Mu] > Pi^2/3, {\[Mu], T}, Reals]


{}

Addition. One can use a ContourPlot instead of a Table to get rid of empty set{}. In order to produce that, one uses  NMinimize to solve eqCase2.
f[A_, e_] := Chop[NMinimize[{(A/
      2 - (-2 T ArcTanh[\[Pi]/Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/3 + 2 \[Mu]]])/
      Sqrt[\[Pi]^2/3 + 2 \[Mu]])^2 + (-e/2 + \[Pi] T + (A \[Mu])/
      2)^2, T < 0 && \[Mu] > Pi^2/3}, {\[Mu], T}, 
MaxIterations -> 300] // First, 10^-20]
ContourPlot[Evaluate[f[A, e]] == 0, {A, 1/100, 1}, {e, 1/100, 1}, PlotPoints -> 25]

You may play with the options of the above commands on your own.


Unfortunately, Resolve[Exists[{\[Mu], T},mueqCase2],Reals] fails on my comp.

Why do I get a different figure than yours with the same code? Version 14.0

@KZ-Spectra:  I am using 14.1 on Windows 10. Up to the documentation, NMinimize has been updated in 14.1.
